# how to implement sizemek conversion tag with adobe dtm?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, adobe-analytics

I wanted to know, how to implement siezmek conversion tag with adobe dtm and what is benefit we are getting to link with adobe dtm?

Answer (score 1):

Implement the conversion tag as a third party JavaScript or HTML tag in a page load rule if it is to be fired on page, or event based rule or direct call rule if the conversion activity is event driven.

Comment: Hi Robert,Thanks for the reply! actually my team has implemented sizemek conversion implementation with scode adobe dtm library.Is this right way to do that?

Comment: @PayalDaryani, If you are asking if can put Sizmek tag in the Custom Code section of the Adobe Analytics tool, it is not the best practice. The Custom Code section in there is meant to load customisations to the variables being sent to Adobe Analytics report suite, and not to load conversion tags. The tool settings should not be touched after the setup is done, and conversion tags do receive more updates than the AA tool settings on the average. As mentioned, such tags are best loaded through page load rule, event based rule or direct call rule.